# pg_dump password authentication failed error with pgpass.conf file in Windows

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I couldn't do a backup because pg_dump shows the following error.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: 
FATAL:  password   authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file 
"C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf"
```

This is what my pgpass file look like.

```
localhost:5432:mydb:postgres:mypassword
```

When I remove pgpass.conf file and run the pg_dump file, it prompts for password and the backup runs properly.

This is what the pg_dump script looks like.

```
set PGPASSFILE=%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
%PG_BIN%pg_dump -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% %DB%
```

This is a Windows scheduled task so I don't want the user to enter the password.

Comment: What values do the variables `%PG_PORT%`, `%PG_USER%` `%PG_HOST%` and `%DB%` contain?

Comment: The port comes from a registry file. user -  postgres, host - localhost, db - mydb

Comment: "*This is a Windows scheduled task*" - under which Windows user does that task run? Is that `MyName`?

Comment: That is right. MyName is a Windows user that is currently logged in and in which the scheduled task runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. The script that creates the pgpass.conf file created a space after the password and that space made the password - mypassword to be wrong. So when I removed the space, it works properly!

The script that created the pgpass file was:

```
echo %PG_HOST%:%PG_PORT%:*:%PG_USER%:%PG_PASSWORD% > %PGPASS_FILE%
```

I changed it to the following. See the space between PG_PASSWORD% and > is removed.

```
echo %PG_HOST%:%PG_PORT%:*:%PG_USER%:%PG_PASSWORD%> %PGPASS_FILE%
```

Comment: You don't actually need to create the file if you have all those value in environment variables anyway.

Comment: The issue is, in Windows Server 2012 R2, the pgpass.conf file have no password set. The file is there but it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally deleted the folder. What I did was create a file in the following directory

> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\postgresql

then added a file

```
pgpass.conf
```

In the file I added

> localhost:5432:*:postgres:password